# VHDL when-else error

Tags: vhdl

I'm new in `VHDL` and have simple errors. I'm trying to create MUX using `when` `else` construction. Errors are two types:

`Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab13.vhd(21) near text "when";  expecting ";"`

`Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab13.vhd(21) near text "else";  expecting ":=", or "<="`

And these errors are for every string with `when` `else`.

And here is the code:

```
entity lab13 is
port (SW : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (17 downto 0);
LEDG : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
LEDR : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (17 downto 0));
end lab13;



architecture logicFunc of lab13 is
begin  
    process
variable a, b, c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) :=0;
begin
    a(0) := SW(0) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(3);
    b(0) := SW(6) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(9);
    c(0) := a(0) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(0);
    LEDG(0) <= c(0) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(12);

    a(1) := SW(1) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(4);
    b(1) := SW(7) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(10);
    c(1) := a(1) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(1);
    LEDG(1) <= c(1) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(13);

    a(2) := SW(2) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(5);
    b(2) := SW(8) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(11);
    c(2) := a(2) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(2);
    LEDG(2) <= c(2) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(14);
end process;
   LEDR <= SW;
end logicFunc;
```

So, how to solve these problems?

Comment: What toolchain are you using?

Comment: @scary_jeff Quartus II 13.0

Comment: Hm, I'm not so familiar with that, but I think the problem is that you need to look in the synthesis or project options and set the VHDL mode to VHDL-2008 or VHDL-200x. See if you can find something like that.

Comment: You're trying to use a sequential conditional assignment statements (in a process) which appear to not be supported in the particular version of Quartus II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `when` in sequential statement for conditional variable or signal assignment was introduced in VHDL-2008, which is not fully supported in Altera Quartus.

The implementation can instead be made with signals, and no process, like:

```
architecture logicFunc of lab13 is
  signal a, b, c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
begin

  a(0) <= SW(0) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(3);
  b(0) <= SW(6) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(9);
  c(0) <= a(0) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(0);
  LEDG(0) <= c(0) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(12);

  a(1) <= SW(1) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(4);
  b(1) <= SW(7) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(10);
  c(1) <= a(1) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(1);
  LEDG(1) <= c(1) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(13);

  a(2) <= SW(2) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(5);
  b(2) <= SW(8) when (SW(15) = '0') else SW(11);
  c(2) <= a(2) when (SW(16) = '0') else b(2);
  LEDG(2) <= c(2) when (SW(17) = '0') else SW(14);

  LEDR <= SW;

end architecture;
```

The initialization value of `a`, `b`, and `c` is not required, and otherwise it must be made using:

```
variable a, b, c : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

If something like `when` is handy before VHDL-2008, then a `tern` function can be written as:

```
function tern(cond : boolean; res_true, res_false : std_logic) return std_logic is
begin
  if cond then
    return res_true;
  else
    return res_false;
  end if;
end function;
```

And then used as:

```
a(0) := tern(SW(15) = '0', SW(0), SW(3));
```

Comment: Or you could use one process and switch to if statements instead of conditional assignment statements. The idea that reducing the number processes from the number of assignments to one would simulate faster.  Concurrent assignments imply separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

The 'WHEN' keyword has 2 contexts within VHDL and are both applicable from VHDL 1993 onwards: 
1. it is used as part of a 'CASE' statement within a process/procedure:

```
CASE xyz IS
  WHEN val1 =>  some sequential statements;
  WHEN val2 =>  some sequential statements;
  WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
END CASE;
```

By replacing the code between the BEGIN/END of you process with this will yeild the correct result whether you are using variables or signals.

2. it can used as a 'WHEN-ELSE' concurrent statement (not in a process/procedure):

   result <= val1 WHEN some conditions are true ELSE
             val2 WHEN some other conditions are true ELSE (OTHERS => '0');

This will also return the required result but as not within a process/procedure will require the 'result' to be either a signal or a shared variable.